# How include pdf_tex files from subfolders?

Tags: pdftex, svg

I am trying to write a separate document in several tex files with several graphics, the organization of my files is as follows:

```
chapter1
  |
  -->chapter1.tex
  -->pictures
    |
    -->picture1.pdf_tex
chapter2
  |
  -->chapter2.tex
  -->pictures
    |
    -->picture2.pdf_tex
```

In each chapter I have to insert svg images converted to pdf_tex with the inkspace tool. So I tried this method found on : [How to include an SVG image in LATEX](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf)

```
In preambule : 

\graphicspath{{Chapitre1/pictures/}}
```

```
In Chapter1.tex : 

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
   \scalebox{0.8}{\input{Chapter1/pictures/picture1.pdf_tex}}
\end{figure}
```

but it doesn't work, can you help me with this please?

Comment: You have three variants for the directory in your example: `chapter1`, `Chapitre1` and `Chapter1`. If you input the `chapter1.tex` into a `main.tex` that is on the same level as the chapter directories, then the path should work there. If you compile `Chapter1.tex` then the path must be different (relative to that location). To get more help, you should make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Maybe you should have a look to package `svg`